# hash the password in the routes file and update

Tags: express, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack

This is `PUT` method I want to hash my password(using passport) & and update it.

```
router.put('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
    console.log('listening');
  User.findOneAndUpdate({resetPasswordToken:req.params.token},{
    password: req.body.password,
    resetPasswordToken: undefined,
    resetPasswordExpires: undefined
  },function(err,user) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err + 'is here');
    } else {
      res.json(user);
    }
  });
    });
```

I want to hast the variable only `password`.How can I hash within this method & then update it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using `Mongoose`. First, create a `pre` method inside your `Schema`.

**UserSchema**

```
const mongoose            = require('mongoose')
    , bcrypt              = require('bcrypt-nodejs')
    , SALT_WORK_FACTOR    = 10;

 const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 ... // schema here
});

/**
 * Hash password with blowfish algorithm (bcrypt) before saving it in to the database
 */
UserSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var user = this;

    // only hash the password if it has been modified (or is new)
    if (!user.isModified('password'))
        return next();

    user.password = bcrypt.hashSync(user.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(SALT_WORK_FACTOR), null);
    next();
});

mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**And then in your route:**

```
router.put('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
    User.findOne({resetPasswordToken: new RegExp('^' + req.params.token + '$', "i")}, function (err, user) {
        if (err)
            return next(err);

        if (!user)
            return res.status(422).json({errors: [{msg: 'invalid reset token'}]});

        user.resetPasswordToken = '';
        user.resetPasswordExpires = '';
        user.password = req.body.password;

        user.save().then(function (user) {
            return res.status(200).json(user);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: yes, I have tried as you said but it 's not hashing the password. I have posted a new question in detail. Please once go through it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51380030/unable-hash-the-password-in-mean-stack