# unable hash the password in mean stack

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose, passport.js, mean-stack

This is the code from routes file.

```
router.put('/reset/:token', function(req, res, next) {
  console.log('reseting the password');
  User.findOne({resetPasswordToken:req.params.token}, function(err, user) {
    if(err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(422).json({errors: [{msg: 'invalid reset token'}]});
    }

    user.resetPasswordToken ='';
    user.resetPasswordExpires = '';
    user.password = req.body.password;
    User.addUser(user, (err, user) => {
      if(err){
        res.json({success: false, msg:'password has not changed'});
      } else {
        res.json({success: true, msg:'password has changed'});
      }
    });
  });
});
```

This part of the code is from my schema file.

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  resetPasswordToken: {
    type: String
  },
  resetPasswordExpires: {
    type: Date
  }

});

  const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
      bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        newUser.password = hash;
        newUser.save(callback);
      });
    });
  }
```

When I try to rest the password it is storing as I've given the input. It is not hashing the password. For example, I have given the password as "zp12345", in the database it is storing as  `"password" : "zp12345".`

Comment: Does the hashing work for creating new users? If not, you might want to use that `bcrypt-nodejs` module instead of the `bcrypt` module as described in the answer below. I've also faced some issues with the `bcrypt` module.

Comment: yes, it works. I have solved it.

Comment: Great! :) You can edit your original post to provide the answer for what was wrong in case some one else is facing similar issues with `passport`.

Answer (score 0):

For solve the problem you need to fix your addUser method:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(10), null, (err, hash) => {
       if (err) {
         return next(err);
       }
       newUser.password = hash;
       newUser.save(callback);
    })
};
```

Here there is another example: [Mongoose Pre Save Changing Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51291633/node-js-schema-presave-is-not-changing-data/51314259#51314259)

And this is the library documentation: [Bcrypt Nodejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt-nodejs)